# jQuery | Keep top div element in view while window scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div element with class `.b-widget` and is present on the top of the page.
When I `scroll down`, the div goes away and when I `scroll up` it appears again.
I want it to stick to its place when i `scroll down` and resume when I `scroll up`.

I wrote below `script` but this is not helping either :

```
<script>
//keep element in view
(function($)
{
    $(document).ready( function()
    {
        var elementPosTop = $('.b-widget').position().top;
        $(window).scroll(function()
        {
            var wintop = $(window).scrollTop(), docheight = $(document).height(), winheight = $(window).height();
            //if top of element is in view
            if (wintop > elementPosTop)
            {
                //always in view
                $('.b-widget').css({ "position":"fixed", "top":"50px" });
            }
            else
            {
                //reset back to normal viewing
                $('.b-widget').css({ "position":"inherit" });
            }
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Comment: it's not exactly clear what is wrong with your code, just looks like you would have an extra 50px top when you reset it.  I would use a class to make it fixed instead of using css directly on your element - that way you do not have to reset all your css back to normal, you can just remove the class that fixes it - see this http://jsfiddle.net/FyEGN/2/

Comment: Or this would be closer to what you are after: http://jsfiddle.net/FyEGN/1515/

Comment: why you do not fixed it for ever in css that take "position":"fixed", "top":"50px"

Comment: @Pete else part is working but not if part.

Her is the code I writtem :

Comment: <style>

.fixed {position:fixed; top:0; left:0; z-index:2; width:100%;}

</style>

<script>

$(window).scroll(function(){
      if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
 $(".flight-filters.ow").css({
                            "display": "none",
                            "opacity": "0"
                        }).fadeOut("slow");
      $('.b-widget > .container-fluid').addClass('fixed');
      } else {
          $('.b-widget > .container-fluid').removeClass('fixed');
      }
  });
</script>

Comment: the element '.b-widget > .container-fluid' is getting hidden inside the body header .

Comment: @AmbikaTewari please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53372705/edit) the question and put the code in a snippet in a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

use css like this:

```
.b-widget{
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```